# general formula $x < N/2$ given $x^2 \bmod N$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does there exist an $N$ for where there is an absolute value type closed-form function e.g., $f(x) = (x^2)^{1/2} \equiv x \bmod N$ where $x<N/2$. That is if we treat $\{0, ... , N/2\}$ as positive and $\{N/2+1, ... N-1\}$ as negative. is there a formula that ensure the value returns back to the original for values $x < N/2$ (i.e., positive).

Tried various forms for $N$, e.g., $N$ a composite, a prime, a power of a prime. Tried to prove a similar result for $x< 1/4\cdot P$ and raise to $(P+1)/4$ for prime $P \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ without success.  Also, Pell's equation seemed hopeful but was not successful.

update based on comments:
objective is to map a homomorphic function  $h(\cdot) : Z_N \rightarrow Z_N$ to a new function $H(x)$ such that $H(x) = H(-x)$, where $-x = N-x$. My attempt to do $H(x) = (h(x)^2)^{1/2} = h((x^2)^{1/2})$ did not work due to the wrap around on the primes when raised to say $(N+1)/4$ for $N$ a prime and $N \equiv 3 \bmod 4$

Comment: I think this is unlikely. If you [edit] the question to ask the question that led to this one we may be able to help.

Comment: I think you're trying to ask, for what positive integers $N$ is there a formula  to find $x\in [1,2,\ldots, \lfloor N/2 \rfloor] $ such that $x^2 \equiv y \pmod N$ for given $y$, assuming $y$ is a square mod $N$.
If $N$ is prime, you can use the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm)

Comment: thank you for your comments. I tried to reframe the question.